# R - collapsing a data.frame by unique ID & generating multiple dummy variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm facing a problem I've been trying to solve for a few days now, and I just can't wrap my head around it. Maybe y'all know of a good solution.

I have a data frame, with approx 3,000,000 rows. **There is one crucial ID variable, with approx 200,000 rows. I want to collapse the data.frame to a new data.frame, which only has 1 row for each unique ID variable value.**

Furthermore, there are a bunch of variables which are also duplicates whenever ID is a duplicate. Here's an example:

```
ID    NAME   CAR
42    Bob    Ford
42    Bob    Ford
42    Bob    Ford
```

However, there are also some variables which vary for a subset of the data frame, which denote specific events or actions taken. Here's an example:

```
ID    NAME   CAR     ACTION    ACTION_ID
42    Bob    Ford    REFILL    4201
42    Bob    Ford    DELIVER   4202
42    Bob    Ford    REFILL    4203
```

What I want, is for this to be flattened to 1 row, but with new dummy variables. Let's assume that `ACTION` has 5 values of interest, `REFILL, DELIVER, PARK, PICKUP, PATROL` in the **ENTIRE** original data.frame. Furthermore, the `ACTION_ID` variable is only relevant to the overall ID, and for every given `ID` variable, there is a maximum number of **5** unique `ACTION_ID` values.

What I'd like to have is dummy variables for every possible combination of `ACTION` and `ACTION_ID`, which would look something like this

```
ID    NAME   CAR     REFILL_01    REFILL_02    REFILL_03    REFILL_04    REFILL_05
42    Bob    Ford    TRUE         FALSE        TRUE         NA               NA

DELIVER_01    DELIVER_02    DELIVER_03    DELIVER_04    DELIVER_05
FALSE         TRUE          FALSE         NA            NA
```

with further dummy variables for `PARK_n, PICKUP_n` and `PATROL_n` whereby `n=1:5`.

I've tried to achieve this with a number of loops whereby I subset the big data.frame by unique ID and then try to generate the new variables and append them to a new data frame. But this never works consistently. I'd be so so grateful if someone had any kind of idea as to how to make this work!

All the best
Nik

Comment: I can do this with dplyr. Can you do this with your dataframe, assuming it is called "df".     dput(head(df,10)). This will give you a big output, copy and paste it so I can test on dummy data.

Comment: thanks for your reply - i'm afraid i can't post the output here because i'd have to redact all the identifying variables in the data. i can however tell you that 
dput(head(df,10))==df is TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work. You will need to write the additional code by hand, but this will solve it for you. I am assuming your dataframe is named "df"

```
library(dplyr)    
new <- df %>% group_by(ID,NAME) %>% mutate(REFILL_01 =
 ifelse(ACTION=="Refill" & substr(ACTION_ID,4,4) == 1,"TRUE","FALSE"),
 REFILL_02 = ifelse(ACTION=="Refill" & substr(ACTION_ID,4,4) == 2, "TRUE","FALSE"))
```

This takes the data, groups it by ID and then NAME. And then we start making the dummy variables. I will walk you through the first one. REFILL_01 equals TRUE if both ACTION=Refill and if the ending number of ACTION_ID is a 1. Otherwise, it gets a false. Let me know if this makes sense or if you need any more clarification. You just need to add the other dummy variable you want now. I did the REFILL_01 and REFILL_02 for you.

Comment: thanks for this. i'll give it a try and report back! and - what does "GO BLUE" mean? excuse my ignorance!

Comment: @nikUoM thanks let me know if you need help making it work. All that is left for you to do is start adding more variables after the second to last parentheses. Ignore the go blue, I thought your name was referencing the University of Michigan

Comment: ah, now it makes sense. no, it refers to University of Manchester (UK).

Comment: The current issue with my code is that it fails to summarise still. The summarise command would be able to give you one observation per individual, but I am having trouble applying it. Hopefully someone sees this and can finish off my code.